# Having trouble importing flask dance into pyCharm

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, flask-login, flask-dance

I'm trying to build an a login page for an application using github oauth and flask_dance. When I try to run the following code I keep getting an error saying that flask_dance could not be found, even though it's installed on this device.

```
try:
    from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
    import random
    import json
    from time import time
    from random import random
    from flask_dance.contrib.github import make_github_blueprint, github
```

I've tried to install to ignore the problem but obviously that didn't work because I cannot build the application without it being able to run. I also can't install flask_dance through the pycharm ide as I did with flask.

Comment: What is the exact error message ? How do you produce it exactly ? How do you know it is already installed ?